# TabLayout Not Binding to Viewpager

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I have a fragment which hosts a `TabLayout` and a `ViewPager`. The host fragment is part of a container that switches based on the item selection of a bottom navigation bar.

For some reason, the ViewPager isn't inflating the fragments, and the TabLayout is unresponsive. When sliding left or right, the indicator stops as soon as you stop sliding, and doesn't snap like it should. And, of course, the fragments don't show.

Here is my code...I'm wondering what I am doing wrong.

#### PopularHolderFragment.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import ai.gab.android.R;
import ai.gab.android.ui.adapters.fragment.PopularFragmentsAdapter;
import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

/**
 * Created by Andrew Quebe on 10/20/2017.
 */

@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
public class PopularHolderFragment extends Fragment {

    @BindView(R.id.tabLayout)
    TabLayout tabLayout;

    @BindView(R.id.viewPager)
    ViewPager viewPager;

    public static PopularHolderFragment newInstance() {
        return new PopularHolderFragment();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_popular_holder, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new PopularFragmentsAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()));

        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Posts"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Users"));
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
}
```

#### PopularFragmentsAdapter.java

```
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

import ai.gab.android.ui.fragments.popular.PopularPostsFragment;
import ai.gab.android.ui.fragments.popular.PopularUsersFragment;

/**
 * Created by Andrew Quebe on 8/7/2017.
 */

public class PopularFragmentsAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public PopularFragmentsAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return PopularPostsFragment.newInstance();
            case 1:
                return PopularUsersFragment.newInstance();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Posts";
            case 1:
                return "Users";
        }
        return super.getPageTitle(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

#### fragment_popular_holder.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.activities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/util_popular_main_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

#### util_popular_main_content.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/fragment_popular_holder">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

#### Screenshots

[image]
[image]

Also wondering why the text isn't its normal size.

Note that I do not want a toolbar in this layout, and perhaps that is my issue, but I don't see why it would be as the widgets should be able to work independently of each other.

Comment: I don't see anything immediately that would necessarily explain the odd sliding behavior, but: You should be using `getChildFragmentManager()` for the `PagerAdapter`, since the `ViewPager` is inside another `Fragment`. The `tabLayout.addTab()` calls are pointless, as they're cleared by the `setupWithViewPager()` call. The `ConstraintLayout` is unnecessary, since it's only holding the `ViewPager`. I'm not sure what you mean by the text size, or toolbar comments.

Comment: This seemed to work! If you type up and answer, I'll mark it. Thanks :)

Comment: Hmm, well, I can't reproduce the described buggy behavior, atm, and I don't like to take credit for fixes I can't explain, so I'm gonna hold off. Do feel free to post the changes you've made as an answer, if you'd like to close out your question. I'll let ya know if I ever pinpoint the issue. Anyhoo, thanks for the offer. Appreciate it. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the comment from [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m) and [AndroidSmoker74's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8746485/androidsmoker74) answer, I was able to fix the TabLayout bug.

#### PopularWrapperFragment.java

```
public class PopularWrapperFragment extends Fragment {

    @BindView(R.id.tabLayout)
    TabLayout tabLayout;

    @BindView(R.id.viewPager)
    ViewPager viewPager;

    public static PopularWrapperFragment newInstance() {
        return new PopularWrapperFragment();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_popular_holder, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setPagingEnabled(false);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new PopularFragmentsAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        return view;
    }
}
```

#### PopularFragmentsAdapter.java

```
public class PopularFragmentsAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public PopularFragmentsAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return PopularPostsFragment.newInstance();
            case 1:
                return PopularUsersFragment.newInstance();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Posts";
            case 1:
                return "Users";
        }
        return super.getPageTitle(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Hope someone finds this useful!

Answer (score 2):

May be my answer is not correct answer for your question. I faced same issue while dealing with Fragments... Below is the mistake I did.

```
return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
```

This was creating this kind of issue. I removed this sentence and just inflated some view from the layout files, then it was working fine.

Just check your `onCreateView` function it will probably solve your problem.

My point is clear here. You should return your inflated view in `onCreateView` function instead of `super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);`

Answer (score 1):

do the binding of pager and tabs in `onCreateView`. Not in the `onActivityCreated`.

And you don't need to manually add tabs to TabLayout, it'll do so automatically.
just get the tabs by position and set their text.

Comment: But I have tablayout in the activity and viewpager in fragment. I need to bind them. 

I cannot move tablayout to the fragment.

Why does the biding fail in `onActivityCreated`. If we know that maybe I can workaround that limitation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

binding should be in onCreateView.